# No puedo subir Imagen con AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un Form en HTML para poder actualizar la imagen de perfil de los usuarios por una propia.

Tengo el AJAX que envía la imagen vía POST al PHP y a su vez el PHP la sube al servidor. El problema es que, si bien el form me deja elegir el archivo, al seleccionar la imagen (onchange), no envía la imagen en cuestión.

Ya intenté hacerlo también haciendo un `trigger(submit)` con `input type submit`, pero ocurre exactamente lo mismo que al usar `on(change)` con el `input type file`.

Les dejo los scripts, si alguien puede decirme qué estoy haciendo mal para así modificarlo, se lo agradezco de antemano.

Script HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-img" method="POST">
<div class="row" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 18px;">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img width="100%" height="auto" src="fotos/<?php echo $_SESSION['logo']; ?>"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <label style="display: block;">Seleccione una imagen de perfil:</label>
        <div hidden><input name="image" type="file"></div>
        <div class="btn-only blue upload" style="margin: 0px;">Buscar</div>
        <span class="img-status"></span>
    </div>
</div><hr>
</form>
```

Script AJAX (jQuery)

```
$(".upload").on("click", function(){
    $("[name=image]").trigger("click");
});
$("[name=image]").on("change", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "functions/cambiar_imagen.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $(".form-img").serialize(),
        success: function(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Script PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
include("serverconfig.php");
include("codificar_clave.php");
include("log.php");

$target_path = "../fotos/";
$target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$temp_path = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_path, $target_path)){
    echo "El archivo ".basename($temp_path). " ha sido subido";
} else {
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error, trate de nuevo!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia data: por FormData.

quedaria algo similar a esto:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "functions/cambiar_imagen.php",
        type: "post",
        data: new FormData($(".form-img")[0]),
contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(e){
success: function(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: La [`API FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#Browser_compatibility) es compatible con `IE10+`

Comment: @MarcosGallardo ¿eso existe todavia?

Comment: Ya probé utilizando formData, pero de ésa manera no ejecuta el Ajax directamente.

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta @IgnazVolkov a mi con eso me funcionó y tampoco me pasaba nada usando formData

Comment: Es lo mismo, me mal interpreté al responderte. La función new formData, ya la utilicé de diversas formas y no hubo forma. De hecho en un momento recuerdo que puse un alert que me dijera con serialize() todos los elementos input que tengan datos a enviar (por ende me tendría que haber tirado algo como a=1&b=2&c=3...) pero me devolvía todo en blanco, tal como si el form no tuviera nada, de hecho me fije en el DOM si el input file tenía algún valor, y funcionaba perfectamente; también quité el div con el hidden y ocurría lo mismo.

Comment: @IgnazVolkov Si ya probaste con el código que te mando y no va no te se ayudar :_( ya te digo que a mi me pasaba lo mismo y al leer el formulario por javascript puro como te he puesto me funcionó a la primera.  También es cierto que yo en vez de clase use un id para el formulario, no se si eso será importante

Comment: @MarcosGallardo pero solo un 4% que son gente que todavía usa el fax y la paloma mensajera

Comment: Creo que aún así vale la pena mencionar la compatibilidad.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo De hecho no lo es, ya que he usado class en vez de id para enviar formularios por Ajax y funcionaban bien.

Comment: @Killpe Probé con id por las dudas, pero sigue igual. Igualmente, gracias por tu aporte. :)

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Perdón, me refería a Killpe, pasa que llevo despierto desde hace 12 horas y como que la cabeza ya la tengo en cualquier lado.

Answer (score 0):

hay amigo yo esta igual que tu esta que hize esto con mi cigigo es para subir un videos y otener una imagen lo mudifique para ti lo hice rapido si tiene un error dime y suerte con tu code :D https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B05fuDZbqNIVbmt0MW8yaEd3Zm8

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

            $('#photoimg').live('change', function()            { 
                       $("#preview").html('');
                $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                        target: '#preview'
        }).submit();

            });
        });
```